# MVC Core 2 project Buttons don't work once published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a MVC core 2 project that works fine on my development server.  Once I publish it to the production server, I can't get any of my buttons to work.  I can navigate to all of the pages, my Javascript and JQuery seem to work fine, but if there is a button, it will not fire upon being clicked.  To be clear, navigation buttons, input buttons (or buttons used for navigation, input, etc.) will not work.

I'm thinking I'm missing some sort of library (bootstrap?), but not sure.  Any ideas of what or how to go about finding what?

## UPDATE

I deleted and uploaded everything again and that took care of my input buttons not working (must have had some old files left in the root); however, I still can't get my navigation buttons to work.  I don't get any errors when I click on them that I can see and below is my nav code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    DropDownTest<span class="caret" style="background-color:transparent;"></span>
                </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
       <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Something1">Something1</a></li>
       <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Something2">Something2</a></li>
       ..etc
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think a bit more information is required here - e.g. any errors in the browser debug console or problems downloading assets/posting back to the server in the browser network tab (404s/500s). However, just as a stab in the dark, are you browsing to the site over the local network using Internet Explorer? If so, check that compatibility mode is not enabled. Makes me panic every time.

Comment: Not using localhost/local network, I'm navigating to the site using an IP address

Comment: Check the developer console of your browser for errors. Some sort of script is missing, so you should have a 404 or a JS error (which could prevent further JS from running, creating the same effect).

Comment: Looks like I've got a script being blocked...Doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do what it is supposed to do. Thanks guys.